# How to display a new class neatly in VSCode Debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, xtensor

I'm working with xtensor arrays, and I cannot figure out how to display them nicely in VSCode's Debugger. This is rather annoying, because I then have to print out the arrays to see the contents.

Is there a way to make a custom function so that I can see the value of the xtensor arrays as what I see when I do std::cout << myArray;

Thank you

Comment: Assuming you have Visual Studio Code sitting atop a gdb for debugging, you're looking to write what's called a Pretty Printer.

Comment: Q: Have you considered downloading Visual Studio (a full-fledged compiler/IDE, but Windows-specific) vs. Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @user4581301, thank you for your reply. I will look into doing that.

Comment: If you include [xio](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xio.html) `#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>` the `std::cout` call will pretty print the array.

Comment: @TaiguaraTupinambás the question was asking how to view the result of std::cout in the debugger console. I will be trying the Pretty Printer approach that user4581301 suggested and I'll report back.