How to view C++ arrays in VS Code debugger
I'm using the Microsoft's C/C++ extension for debugging and the outputs for arrays look like:

If something changes in the array, I have to click to see inside.
How can I make it show all the elements like python debugger:

Edit: I forgot to enable pretty printing for strings.

If such tuning is not available, you can make/propose changes in the sources code https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools or request a change there.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54941596/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67289933/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56828562/11107541

Which debugger are you using?

This one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools @fdan

joy, that debugger is backed by a toolchain debugger like gdb, lldb, or visual studio's debugger. that might have been what fdan was asking you.

Something that I have occasionally had more luck with is the "watch" window.

You can add specific variables and it generally shows changes better.
For example,
arr[0]
or potentially
std::to_string(s) (assuming s is a char[] or char* of some sort) could be added.
This window can found under the run and debug tab by default.
I think your difference is likely due to c++ being compiled while python is interpreted. This means it's easier for vscode to "peek" into the variables--but that's just a guess.
